# How can I solve same site attribute problem in Chrome80?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, samesite

My website developed by asp.net core 5

The website has added a third-party js package for statistics(Something like Google Analytics).

However, chrome now report these:

```
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.
23 cookies
9 requests
```

I only found a tutorial about this by adding this code in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```

However, it doesn't work any. Chrome still reports the error.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

===================================

Here is the cookies-page in DevTools of Chrome：
[image]

The red block is my website and the other is the third-party js package.

Comment: Have u add `app.UseCookiePolicy();` in `Configure` method like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-5.0#supporting-older-browsers)？What is your statistics package?

Comment: @MichaelWang Yes, I have added this before. The statistics package is Baidu Statistics. This problem was also available on the Baidu/Bytedance/360 push service(js package).

Comment: @MichaelWang I have followed this tutorial, and it is useless also. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Comment: Have u called `UseCookiePolicy` before `UseAuthentication` or any method that writes cookies in Startup.Configure?  If yes,  check the settings of your chrome. Deselect Block third-party cookies on chrome://settings/content/cookies.

Comment: @MichaelWang Yes, I did this already. The block setting in my chrome is Block third-party cookies in Incognito. What's more, I added some detail to my question. I knew less about Samesite and I doubt now the problem maybe is Baidu but not my website.